# How to read from a file in my application on android?

Tags: android, file, storage

I created a file on my pc, and I want my app to read from it.

How do I read from that file in my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Put the file in `assets/` (e.g., `app/src/main/assets/` in a typical Android Studio project). Then use `open()` on an `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` on that content. You can get an `AssetManager` from your `Activity` or other `Context` by calling `getAssets()`.

Comment: Thank You! very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Move your file to card and add path instead of "file.txt"

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }

    br.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
//You'll need to add proper error handling here
}

//Find the view by its id
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);

//Set the text
tv.setText(text);
```

it example best if you want to read text